# Why is my google apps script passing a value in one function and a NaN in the other?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using the doGet() example code for passing values from a hidden object.  It works in the first case of adding a column but on the delcolumn I get a NaN/Undefined in my logger.  Trying to figure out why as the code looks identical to Google Tutorial.

```
function onOpen() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var menuEntries = [ {name: "BuildUI", functionName: "BuildUi"} ];
  ss.addMenu("BuildUI", menuEntries);

}


function BuildUi() 
  {



 var appheight =360
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(500).setHeight(appheight).setTitle('Step 1:  PickBoxes');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("settingsPanel");

  var headerpanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("headerPanel").setStyleAttribute("background", "silver").setWidth(500);
  var columnPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var mainGrid = app.createGrid(5, 1).setId("mainGrid");
  var scroller =app.createScrollPanel();
  var hidinstallcolumns =app.createTextBox().setId("hidinstallcolumns").setName("hidinstallcolumns").setValue("1");

  var columnGrid =app.createGrid(1,1).setId("columnGrid");
  var headerlabel = app.createLabel("Headerlabel").setStyleAttribute("background", "silver").setWidth(500);
  headerlabel.setText('Please Add Text')

  //Set up Selection for columns
  var columnspanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("columnspanel");
  var columnname = app.createTextBox().setText("Name");
  var columntype = app.createListBox();
  var columnlabel = app.createLabel("1");
  var columndelhandler = app.createServerClickHandler("columndel").addCallbackElement(hidinstallcolumns);

  var columndelbutton = app.createButton().setText("X").addClickHandler(columndelhandler);  
  columntype.addItem("1");
  columntype.addItem("2");
  columntype.addItem("3");
  columntype.addItem("4");  
  columnspanel.add(columnlabel);

  columnspanel.add(columnname);
  columnspanel.add(columntype);
 columnspanel.add(columndelbutton);
  //    
  var addcolumnspanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("addcolumnspanel");
  var addbuttonhandler = app.createServerClickHandler("addcolumn").addCallbackElement(hidinstallcolumns);

  var addbutton = app.createButton().setId("btnaddcolumn").setText("Add another column").addClickHandler(addbuttonhandler);  

  addcolumnspanel.add(addbutton);   
  columnGrid.setWidget(0, 0, columnspanel);
  scroller.add(columnGrid);
  scroller.setHeight(appheight-80);
  mainGrid.setWidget(0, 0, headerlabel);
  mainGrid.setWidget(1, 0, scroller);
  mainGrid.setWidget(2, 0, addcolumnspanel);

  panel.add(mainGrid);

  app.add(panel);
  ss.show(app);
    Logger.log("Fully DoNe");
  return app;
}


 function addcolumn(e) {

  var app =UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var mybutton = app.getElementById("btnaddcolumn");
   mybutton.setEnabled(false);
   var columnrownumbers =  parseFloat(e.parameter.hidinstallcolumns);
   Logger.log("printcolumns");
   Logger.log(columnrownumbers);
   columnrownumbers++;
   Logger.log(columnrownumbers);
   var mytarg = app.getElementById("hidinstallcolumns");
   mytarg.setText(columnrownumbers.toString());
  var delhidstr = "del" + columnrownumbers.toString();
  Logger.log(delhidstr); 
   var columnnum =app.createHidden(delhidstr.toString(),columnrownumbers).setId("columnnum");
  var columngrid = app.getElementById('columnGrid');
  var columnspanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("columnspanel");
  var columnname = app.createTextBox().setText("Name");
  var columntype = app.createListBox();
  var columnlabel = app.createLabel(columnrownumbers);
  app.add(columnnum);
  var columndelhandler = app.createServerHandler("columndel").addCallbackElement(columnnum);
  var columndelbutton = app.createButton().setText("X").addClickHandler(columndelhandler);  
  columntype.addItem("1");
  columntype.addItem("2");
  columntype.addItem("3");
  columntype.addItem("4");
   columnspanel.add(columnlabel);
  columnspanel.add(columnname);
  columnspanel.add(columntype); 
  columnspanel.add(columndelbutton);
  columngrid.resize(columnrownumbers, 1); 
  var location = columnrownumbers;
  location = location -1;
  columngrid.setWidget(location ,0,columnspanel);
  mybutton.setEnabled(true);
  return app; 


}

  function columndel(eventInfo)
{
  var app =UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(eventInfo.parameter.columnnum); //Keeps getting undefined
  Logger.log(parseFloat(eventInfo.parameter.columnnum)); //Keeps getting NaN
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var columnnum` has no `.setName()`

Comment: Now I feel like a Jackass since I've spent 4 hours trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct, when you create the hidden widget using

```
   var columnnum =app.createHidden(delhidstr.toString(),columnrownumbers).setId("columnnum");
```

you implicitely gave it a name (see [doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-instance#createHidden%28String,String%29)) as the first string parameter is actually the widget's name.

So the error was that you tried to get the value using the **wrong name** and not a widget without name.